# Chrome Freezing?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, freeze

Google Chrome Browser is freezing every 10-15 seconds in Windows 7. I even formatted the system and reinstalled Windows 7 but to no avail. Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: Could you check if the system is paging when chrome freezes?

Comment: The most likely issue is that your hard-disk is failing, and when your process is page-faulting and trying to get pages back from the pagefile you're disk is taking too long to respond. The process is suspended during the query from the pagefile, and so you experience the process freezing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be taking a serious look at your hardware - If a fresh install of windows 7 and google chrome stable is crashing that often, something is very wrong.

To elaborate, run [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/), [prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/), et cetera.